# Mordell's Trick for Evaluating the Gauss Sum - How to calculate the residues?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory

Define $$f(z) = \frac{A(z)}{B(z)} = \frac{\exp(2 \pi i z^2 / n)}{\exp(2 \pi i z) - 1}$$

How do I calculate the Residues of $f$?

---

My approach was look for singularities by setting the denominator to zero, in other words looking for $z$ such that $\exp(2 \pi i z) = 1$. So I think that the poles would be at $z = k \in \mathbb Z$. But according to the solution (which is not a full solution, just some good hints) there are residues at every $k/2$. Why does this happen?

For computing the Residue values I reasoned that the poles have order 1 since the denominator is not zero after differentiating it. The numerator is nonzero so I can calculate the residues as $$\operatorname{Res}(f;k) =  A(k)/B'(k) = \frac{\exp(2 \pi i k^2 / n)}{2 \pi i \exp(2 \pi i k)} = \frac{\exp(2 \pi i k^2 / n)}{2 \pi i}$$

Now this value looks reasonable to me based on the Gauss sum I'm aiming to evaluate but I'm confused about the $k/2$ comment. Is this valid and have I missed other singularities I need to worry about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Why does this happen?" It doesn't happen. The $k/2$ business is a mistake. I'm not sure what kind of "solution manual" you are looking at, but know this: Solution manuals, the books themselves, even Fields Medal winners: They all make mistakes at times.

We know the numerator never vanishes. The denominator vanishes only when $e^{2\pi i z}=1,$ and as you said, that only happens when $2\pi i z = 2\pi i k$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z.$ In other words, when $z\in \mathbb Z.$

For example, take $k=1.$ Does our expression have a singularity at $k/2 = 1/2?$ No, because both numerator and denominator are nonzero at $1/2.$

Your reasoning is entirely correct, your computation of the residues is correct, and there is not much more that I can add.